# How can I handle an exception form outside method body in java?

Tags: java, exception

Consider following code:

```
public class A
{
   static final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The above code seems to work fine. However, when I use the following:

```
public class A
{
   static final ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
}
```

Here, I see an unhandled exception of type IOException.
I tried the **try-catch** block and **throws** keyword.
I am unable to solve this problem by using the above two. It is possible that they work but can't figure out how. Is there any way to handle this exception?
Currently using JDK 7.

Comment: you have to do the initialization in a method. Its not possible to catch a exception from static block.
use a static method: `public static void init(){//here your code}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Provate method

You can create a `ServerSocket` using static private method, and inside this method you can handle a exception and do something what you want.

```
public class A
    static final ServerSocket ss = createServerSocket();

    private static ServerSocket createServerSocket() {
        try {
            return new ServerSocket(6666);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

### Static block

Another way is using a static block. Then your code could looks like this.

```
public class A {
    static final ServerSocket ss;

    static {
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Static block will not work as you said. if the variable is `final`, you need to initialize it, otherwise make error

Comment: Code is throwing RunTimeException which will completely kill application.

Comment: @Abdul Razak everything work fine. Check yourself if you don't believe.

Comment: @Rohit Khatkar it is only sample. Of course instead of throw RuntimeException, you can do something else. Everything depend what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that, but the best one is using a init method, so you can handle the exception and your code is reuseable.

So just define a static init method in your class

```
public class A{
   static ServerSocket ss;

   public static void init(int port) throws IOException{
      ss = new ServerSocket(port);
   }
}
```

This code let you hande the exception by providing it to the higher instance (caller) and it let you reuse the code in another programm (port number is not fix).

Another way is a static block with inner exception handling, it is not a good idea to use it, because its hard to mantain it and the exception handling is realy hard

```
static {
   try {
      ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Comment: the variable `ss` final. so you cannot use `static` block

Comment: even the first one won´t work with final keyword. Final variables have to be initialized in the same line as they are declared. It would only work if init would return a new serverSocket, but then exception handling is not realy possible (only inside init)

Answer (score 0):

Use static initialization block to catch exception like this:

```
public class A {
    static final ServerSocket ss;

    static {
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```